# Multi tenancy in Spring boot and React

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, rest, multi-tenant

I am trying to develop a REST API in spring boot and having React as the frontend. React will send GET or POST requests happening on the frontend to modify the MySQL DB in the backend via REST API. In my application, A user can have multiple companies inside the application and each company data is isolated from one another. I have come across Multi-Tenancy in Spring boot. **How can I do this implementation for REST API ?? How can I configure my React application for this multi-tenancy?? Is Reactive Core in spring is useful??.** Any resources where I can find these answers so that I can implement it. Or any other better way to implement this use case. Please, someone help me. Google results have confused me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could read a lot about this if you focus on little more details than a broad topic search in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spring%20boot%20multitenancy)

Here is one way you can achieve your requirement.

1. React App authenticates your end-users
2. There will be an API call from UI to get the list of accessible tenants
3. The list of tenants will be shown in the UI like in a dropdown
4. The end user will choose a tenant
5. Once chosen, untill a change next time, you will pass the selected tenant in all the API request headers so that you are identifying the tenant context of the user that is requesting for the data.

Regarding the data-isolation, you do have a lot of options explained in stackoverflow and people have multiple approaches depending on the multi-tenancy levels of course.

The above are the steps that you could achieve in any language (java in your case)

In case of choosing whether your API's are `Reactive` depends on the business needs. However you should be able to weigh the differences between the `aync` and `reactive` implementations, both have their needs, so identify the requirement and choose an approach that suits.

In case you need help in choosing the right approach for a given scenario, do share with us the scenario, how you did it and what you have issue / doubt and the community will be happy to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your helped me to clear some things. How can I contact you @Saravanan ? I need some help in choosing the right approach for my scenario. I just need to know the way I need to approach. I am very new to spring